# How to load_image() in Halide with 4 channels instead of 3?

Tags: image-processing, halide

I want to get a 4 channel image instead of 3 while loading it in Halide, however load_image() gives only 3 channel images. How can I solve it?

Comment: Can you post more detail, such as the image you're trying to load? Halide's `load_image` function is designed to handle 4- channel images (we even use RGBA pngs in our nightly testing).

Comment: I'm loading an image, which is an RGB png image. Perhaps, the reason why I don't get an RGBA image is that because the original image is RGB. I want to know whether there is a way to load the image such that it is loaded as an RGBA image with all alpha values set to 255.

Comment: No, that's not how `load_image` works. If you want that, write a func that adds the channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Halide's `load_image` function simply loads an image file off the disk. If it's RGB, it will have three channels, if it's RGBA, it will have four channels. This is working as intended.

If you want to add a channel to your image during a pipeline, then you can write:

```
Buffer<uint8_t> input = load_image(...);

Func alpha_255;
alpha_255(x, y, c) = select(c == 3, 255, input(x, y, c));
```

Then you can schedule that func however you want. Most likely you'll end up inlining it into a consumer that has its innermost channel dimension unrolled to get rid of the `select`.